# Implementiung software as web client on Windows CE

Tags: web-applications, compact-framework, windows-ce

when we create mobile software for our customers, we usually create a .net compact framework client that communicates with a server via TCP/IP. As updating all devices (sometimes more than 20) with new software versions can take a long time, we're considering implementing "thin client solutions" in the future, meaning that we only create a .NET application that contains a webbrowser control that points to a web application, which does the work.

Question is: how can we do this and make it most comfortable for the user? Most of our applications require one or more barcode scans within a form. Also, sometimes the user must enter data manually. Also, we want the user to use the touch  screen as little as possible. All fields should be accessible via keyboard shortcuts.

Is that possible at all? What are your experiences with things like that?

Any input is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've now implemented a solution that works quite well.